# Does Redmine provide any graph report options

Tags: redmine-plugins

Does Redmine tool provide any plugin to generate graphs for the issues?

Like, i need to generate a pie or bar graph for no. of issues raised for current week/month etc. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed some Redmine plugins that provide graphical reports. Some of them (more or less) usable also for issues. The free one's are listed on Redmine.org in the plugin directory, the others are commercial plugins. 
Like the following one's:

- [Redmine Reporting Plugin](https://alphanodes.com/en/redmine-reporting)
- [Plugin for the Redmine issue tracker](http://redmine.forkbrain.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be:

1. Make your custom queries
2. In every of these queries export the csv file
3. Take it from excel